# Repeatedly apply functions to multiple vectors in multiple R data frames

Tags: r, list, apply, lapply

I have four lists (l1, l2, l3, l4) with a largely identical list of vectors (v1, v2, v3) -- that is, there are a few additional vectors in each successive list, but I am concerned here only with the three vectors that share the names above.

In each list, the data is structured roughly as follows:

```
v1 v2 v3
1 2 4
3 5 2
1 3 2
```

For each list separately, what I need to do is the following:

1) Square each element in the vectors:

```
s1 s2 s3
1 4 16
9 25 4
1 9 4
```

2) Return the mean and standard deviation of each new vector:

```
vector mean_of_s_vec (sd_of_s_vec)
s1 3.67 (4.61)
s2 12.67 (10.96)
s3 8 (6.92)
```

3) Then for each row in the newly squared vectors (step 1), I need to divide each element by the row-wise sum across the three vectors. The value is then a proportion of the denominator. I will add a denominator column to make this clear:

```
p1 p2 p3 denominator
.05 .19 .76 21
.24 .66 .11 38
.07 .64 .29 14
```

4) Calculate the mean and standard deviation of the new p* vectors:

```
vector mean_of_p_vec (sd_of_p_vec)
p1 .12 (.10)
p2 .50 (.27)
p3 .39 (.34)
```

Then I need to repeat these steps for each of the four lists. I have had some luck with apply functions in the past, but so far there are too many steps in the process for me to consolidate everything. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should write a function that takes a list with three vectors as input and perform the calculations that you mentioned. Then you can think of using `lapply`.

Comment: transpose the matrix of vector and apply the `lapply ` function to the matrix with `FUN = #your_function`, argument. Do it for all your lists.